# How do you track a shopify line item script?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I have written some custom line item discount scripts, but I don’t know how to get them tracked in the Shopify analytics/admin? Do any of you know ways to track Shopify script discounts? I tried adding a custom checkout attribute, but that doesn’t show up when someone uses Shopay and seems buggy.